# Python list with filter function (excel-way)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, filtering

I have a Python list:

```
listx = [["a", 127, "Blue", 0],
         ["b", 127, "Red", 1],
         ["b", 127, "Green", 0],
         ["b", 99, "Green", 1],
         ["c", 99, "Yellow", 0]]
```

This is table view for understanding the situation better way:

[image: This is table view]

I want to do some filter function. For example; I want to get a list with **index 0 = "b"** and **index 1 = 127**. So the results must be:

```
listxnew = [["b", 127, "Red", 1],
            ["b", 127, "Green", 0]]
```

Table view for listxnew to understand the situation better way:

[image]

So how can I do this with simple Python code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy solution, which is readily extensible:

```
def filterls(ls, opts):
    """
    ls - list
    opts - dict - {id: match_info}
    """
    results = []
    for l in ls:
        for (i, t) in opts.items():
            if l[i] != t:
                break
        else:
            results.append(l)
    return results
```

For your example:

```
listx = [["a", 127, "Blue", 0],
         ["b", 127, "Red", 1],
         ["b", 127, "Green", 0],
         ["b", 99, "Green", 1],
         ["c", 99, "Yellow", 0]]

print filterls(listx, {0: 'b', 1: 127})
# [['b', 127, 'Red', 1], ['b', 127, 'Green', 0]]
```

Comment: I think this is only for Python 2.7. I got this with Python 3.4: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'viewitems'

Comment: @user3051668 - Yes, in python 3.4, viewitems is just items. Edited.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using list comprehension as follows:

```
listxnew = [i for i in listx if i[0:2]==['b', 127]]

>>> print listxnew
[['b', 127, 'Red', 1]
 ['b', 127, 'Green', 0]]
```

Comment: This is not a way that I want. Any def, function, or something like that? I will use this for a GUI. So, things can be filtered may be more than two, three or just one.

Comment: @user3051668, I'm not sure exactly what you mean but you can easily make a `def` out of the code above. Sorry

Comment: @user3051668 - Check if my answer works? I'm curious whether that's what you're looking for.

Comment: It works, but I don't want to write different codes for different filterings. If I want to filter with index 0 and index 2, it'll be different list comprehension.

Comment: @user3051668 You could readily put the list comprehension in a function and have it based on certain inputs (such as the indices you want to check and their desired value)

Answer (score 1):

```
listx = [["a", 127, "Blue", 0],
         ["b", 127, "Red", 1],
         ["b", 127, "Green", 0],
         ["b", 99, "Green", 1],
         ["c", 99, "Yellow", 0]]

listnew = filter(lambda x: x[0]=='b' and x[1]==127,listx)

print listnew
```

try using [Filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter)

Comment: print listnew gives me <filter object at 0x0345DCF0>, am i missing something?

Comment: @user3051668 no it prints filtered list

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар OP is using Python 3.x, I think.

Comment: @user3051668: just put `list(listnew)` to see what filter is producing under Python 3.x. +1 -- this is the best way IMHO